# list first post of Child Category on Category page

Tags: categories, children

This may be a bit overcomplicated but this is exactly what my client is asking for and if there is anyway to accomplish this task it would be much appreciated. I've found lots of examples of just listing the name of the subcategory, but we need to be able to actually output the content of the first post in each category.

We have several Parent Categories, each with several subCategories.

On the parent Category page we would like to list the first post (only) of each subCategory.

We would also like to achieve this with some sort of "current category" code to avoid having to create a new template file each time a new category is added.

Please let me know if this is not clear enough or if you need more information!

Comment: Can you post your code so far?

Comment: I have no code so far. I haven't a clue how to even start something like this. I imagine it would mostly be custom php code.

Comment: Are there any grandparent categories? A category page with a child of a child category that needs to be displayed.

Comment: No, there are no grandparent categories.